Phaser.Scale.EXACT_FIT creating a proportionate square
In phaser I have set my config with the settings below
const config = {
  type: Phaser.CANVAS,
  width: window.screen.width,
  height: window.screen.height,
  scale: {
    mode: Phaser.Scale.EXACT_FIT,
    parent: 'game-container', 
    width: window.screen.width,
    height: window.screen.height
  },
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade'
  },
  scene: [PreloadScene, PlayScene, QuestionScene]
};

I'm trying to create a proportionate square my problem is the width is longer than height. Is there a solution for this I really need thePhaser.Scale.EXACT_FIT. Check the attach picture

Can you describe, what exactly is the issue? Is the image the desired solution? or the problem? what is drawn on your canvas? ....? an MRE might help understand the issue better.

@winner_joiner as you can see the puzzle board width is longer compared to its height even thought they have same value. And you see the standing block it's stretch compare to flat block

@winner_joiner Or I should try a different approach like using mode: Phaser.Scale.EXACT_FIT then load the background image in html then to fill the screen? Is this possible?

Sure the easy solution would be to use a background image, but than you would have to use a different mode.
